# What is the process Windows takes to open a file?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to understand the general process Windows uses to open a file set with a default program. I recently installed an application that 'replaced' the default opening application for a file type, and I'm trying to figure out the way the file was opened previously (I'd like to use both). So I went back to an earlier version of my computer that had the original program installed, and tried looking under Default Programs to see if I could find a way of viewing what exactly a default program means.

In my understanding, files are opened by calling the executable 'main' programs (with perhaps some arguments?) with the file to open as a parameter. But how exactly do you find the path of the executable being used to run the program, and how do you determine any special arguments (if any) provided to it?

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `assoc.exe` and `ftype.exe`. Here's an example using a Word document:

```
C:\>assoc .doc
.doc=Word.Document.8

C:\>ftype Word.Document.8
Word.Document.8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
```

You can also look at the registry using `regedit.exe`, under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (aka `HKCR`). Start by finding the entry for `.doc`, and then look at the value of `(Default)`, which gives you `Word.Document.8`. Now look further down in `HKCR` to find `Word.Document.8`, and then look at the entries under `shell`; `(Default)` gives you the default action to execute when the file is double-clicked in Explorer, and the subkeys give you the specific command line that is used. You can also see the other available actions that are registered (if any); they'll show up on the context menu if the user right-clicks the file in Explorer.